# How to correct Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?) in csv e netcdf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote code to use csv and netcdf files at the same time and output temperature, but I keep getting an error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import netCDF4
import numpy
import csv
import os
import sys


Arq_CSV = "/home/mayna/Downloads/teste/B116353_2018_FILTRADO.csv"
star = "0000-OSISAF-L3C_GHRSST-SSTsubskin-GOES16-ssteqc_goes16_"
end = "0000-v02.0-fv01.0.nc"


CSV = open(Arq_CSV, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(CSV)


for line in reader:
    if line[0] > '0':
        if (int(line[4]) < 10) and (int(line[5]) < 10) and (int(line[6]) < 10):
            data = line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + str(0) + line[6] + star + line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + "_" + str(0) + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) < 10) and (int(line[5]) < 10) and (int(line[6]) > 9):
            data = line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + line[6] + star + line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + "_" + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) < 10) and (int(line[5]) > 9) and (int(line[6]) < 10):
            data = line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + line[5] + str(0) + line[6] + star + line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + line[5] + "_" + str(0) + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) < 10) and (int(line[5]) > 9) and (int(line[6]) > 9):
            data = line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + line[5] + line[6] + star + line[3] + str(0) + line[4] + line[5] + "_" + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) > 9) and (int(line[5]) < 10) and (int(line[6]) < 10):
            data = line[3] + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + str(0) + line[6] + star + line[3] + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + "_" + str(0) + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) > 9) and (int(line[5]) < 10) and (int(line[6]) > 9):
            data = line[3] + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + line[6] + star + line[3] + line[4] + str(0) + line[5] + "_" + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) > 9) and (int(line[5]) > 9) and (int(line[6]) < 10):
            data = line[3] + line[4] + line[5] + str(0) + line[6] + star + line[3] + line[4] + line[5] + "_" + str(0) + line[6] + end

        elif (int(line[4]) > 9) and (int(line[5]) > 9) and (int(line[6]) > 9):
            data = line[3] + line[4]  + line[5] + line[6] + star + line[3] + line[4]  + line[5] + "_" + line[6] + end

        LON_CSV = line[8]
        LAT_CSV = line[9]
        TEM_CSV = line[10]


        for _,_,files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                if (name == data):
                    NC = netCDF4.Dataset(name)
                    NC.variables.keys()
                    LON_NC = NC.variables['lon']
                    LAT_NC = NC.variables['lat']
                    TEM_NC = NC.variables['sea_surface_temperature']
                    novo = "CSV_NC" + name
                    NOVO_CSV = csv.writer(open(novo, "wb"))
                    NOVO_CSV.writerow(["LON_CSV","LAT_CSV","TEM_CSV","LON_NC","LAT_NC","TEM_CSV"])
                    NOVO_CSV.writerow([LON_CSV,LAT_CSV,TEM_CSV,LON_NC,LAT_NC,TEM_CSV])
```

It keep raising the error:

```
---> 19 for line in reader:
     20         if line[0] > "0":
     21                 if (int(line[4]) < 10) and (int(line[5]) < 10) and (int(line[6]) < 10):  

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open in text mode (it's bytes by default).  I put UTF-8 for the encoding below because it's fairly standard but that should be adjusted as well to your encoding for your file.

```
CSV = open(Arq_CSV, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8')
```